# Use of os.replace with a list of extensions

Tags: python-3.x, python-os

this is my first post at all and I am completely new to Python, like, super-beginner.
I am trying to write a file organizer but I got stuck in a very simple issue: I'd like to move all the files inside a directory, filtered by their extensions.

So, for example, I'd like to move all the images files, which of course can have different extensions.
From my basic understanding of the os.replace function, the argument path should be ("old/path/to/exact/file", "new/path/to/exact/file").
I succeeded in using the os.replace function when there is a single extension, for example ("old/path/to/exact/file/*.pdf", "/new/path/to/exact/file/"), but what it happens when I have a list of extensions?

I already tried to use:

`extension = (".jpg", ".png", ".bmp", ".jpeg", ".gif", ".heic", ".heif")`

and then stuff like

```
if file.endswith((estensione_immagini)):
                os.replace("C:/Users/x/Downloads/", "C:/Users/x/Downloads/Immagini")
```

but it's not working.
I know I probably am lacking the basics of Python, but I need to write something in order to learn it.
Any costructive comment is accepted, thank you so much.

Comment: `os.replace("C:/Users/x/Downloads/", "C:/Users/x/Downloads/Immagini")` moves the *entire* `Downloads` directory.  I would expect to see a reference to `file` somewhere in that line.

Comment: You might take a look at the built-in [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) package, as it can make this kind of work quite a bit easier.

Comment: @0x5453 thanks for the suggestion. I know that the first command would move the entire Downloads directory, it's just I do not know how to add the *.ext filter while having a list / tuple of extensions stored into "extension = (".jpg", ".png", ".bmp", ".jpeg", ".gif", ".heic", ".heif")

I will have a look at the PathLib package